# Drag-and-Drop functionality in Rally Tables

Tags: rally

I need to allow the re-ranking of the stories by implementing the drag-and-drop function inside the rally tables that I have created. How may I implement the drag-and-drop buttons that is available from rally into my rally app using the rally tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable drag and drop ranking under:

Setup --> Workspace + Projects --> Edit Workspace --> Rank Method

More info [here](http://www.rallydev.com/help/prioritizing-work?basehost=https://community.rallydev.com).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately right now the App SDK's Table component does not support drag and drop re-ranking.  However we will be releasing a more powerful Grid component in the next version of the App SDK this spring/summer that will likely include this functionality.